# Kubernetes Ingress - is the Ingress definition required for TCP also or only for HTTP/HTTPS traffic?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have defined my service app running on port 9000. It is not web/http server it is simply just a service application running as windows service on that port to which other apps connect to (outside the container).
So I have defined Port 9000 in my service definition and in my config map definition. We are using NGINX as a proxy for accessing from outside and everything works.

Nginx Service:

```
  - name: 9000-tcp
    nodePort: 30758
    port: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
```

Config Map:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  "9000": default/frontarena-ads-aks-test:9000
kind: ConfigMap
```

Service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontarena-ads-aks-test
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9000
  selector:
    app: frontarena-ads-aks-test
```

Ingress definition:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ads-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: frontarena-ads-aks-test
              servicePort: 9000
```

As mentioned everything works. I know that TCP is used for L4 layer and HTTP for L7 Application Layer.
I need to access my  app from another app solely by its hostname and port. Without any HTTP Url.
So basically does it mean that I do NOT need actually my Ingress Controller definition at all?
I do not need to deploy it at all?
I would only need it if I need HTTP access with some URL for example: `hostname:port/pathA or hostname:port/pathB`

Is that correct? For regular TCP connection we do not need at all our Ingress YAML definition? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you don't need ingress at all in this case. According to kubernetes official doc, Ingress is:

> An API object that manages external access to the services in a cluster, typically HTTP.

So, if you don't need any external access via http, you can omit ingress.

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/